# using Sed with grep for the log file

Tags: php, linux, logging, command-line, terminal

I was trying to make php error logs visibly good
whenever I do error_log($ex->getTraceAsString()) but it printed \n so I figured out the possibilities, it turned out that I should do that from terminal itself

so I do

```
 tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

But Previously for my logs I used to do

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep production
```

for logs that contains the keyword production

But I want both of them what should I do?.So that my both criteria worked

I tried

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep production | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | sed 's/\\n/\n/g' | grep production 
(tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep production) | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
(tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | sed 's/\\n/\n/g') | grep production
```

But none of these worked. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the search string to the sed statement with /..../ and so:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | sed -n '/production/s/\\n/\n/gp'
```

Comment: How is this different from `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep production | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'`?

Comment: It didn't worked, I got the logs that contains the lines that doesn't contains production

Comment: Apologies. You will need -n. I have amended the answer.

Comment: Hi @RamanSailopal,sorry but you solution didn't worked for {"time":"2021-01-28 19:26:07.402946", "function" : "[-:error]","process" : "[pid25953]" ,"message" : "PHP Warning:  get_headers(https://www.google.com/philips-for-sofware-technologist-ii/): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/production/file.php on line 158","host":"production.google.org"}

Comment: it consists production but this line isn't shown if I used th solution you wrote. Although if i do normal tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep production. It works (but then the new line issue will not be solved)